# running a pytorch distributed application on a single 4 gpu-machine

Tags: python, deep-learning, parallel-processing, pytorch, distributed-computing

I want to run the code from https://github.com/facebookresearch/moco at my 4-GPU machine
(4 nvidia A100 running cuda) for training a neural network.

The needed training dataset is saved at the same machine

But if I starting the main script following the Instruction in the Readme file
the programm get stuck and there is no training code executed. (execution stops at some point in the script)

I run the script with the command

```
python main_moco.py \
  -a resnet50 \
  --lr 0.03 \
  --batch-size 256 \
  --dist-url 'tcp://localhost:10001' --multiprocessing-distributed --world-size 1 --rank 0 \
  [your imagenet-folder with train and val folders]
```

The world size is 1 according to using a single machine, hence it gets the first existing rank = 0

But I don't understand the --dist-url parameter. It is used as the init_method of the dist.init_process_group function each node of the cluster calls at start, I guess.

How do I have to configure the parameters for successfully running the distributed pytorch script ?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch ImageNet Training')
parser.add_argument('data', metavar='DIR',
                    help='path to dataset')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--arch', metavar='ARCH', default='resnet50',
                    choices=model_names,
                    help='model architecture: ' +
                        ' | '.join(model_names) +
                        ' (default: resnet50)')
parser.add_argument('-j', '--workers', default=32, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='number of data loading workers (default: 32)')
parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=200, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='number of total epochs to run')
parser.add_argument('--start-epoch', default=0, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='manual epoch number (useful on restarts)')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=256, type=int,
                    metavar='N',
                    help='mini-batch size (default: 256), this is the total '
                         'batch size of all GPUs on the current node when '
                         'using Data Parallel or Distributed Data Parallel')
parser.add_argument('--lr', '--learning-rate', default=0.03, type=float,
                    metavar='LR', help='initial learning rate', dest='lr')
parser.add_argument('--schedule', default=[120, 160], nargs='*', type=int,
                    help='learning rate schedule (when to drop lr by 10x)')
parser.add_argument('--momentum', default=0.9, type=float, metavar='M',
                    help='momentum of SGD solver')
parser.add_argument('--wd', '--weight-decay', default=1e-4, type=float,
                    metavar='W', help='weight decay (default: 1e-4)',
                    dest='weight_decay')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--print-freq', default=10, type=int,
                    metavar='N', help='print frequency (default: 10)')
parser.add_argument('--resume', default='', type=str, metavar='PATH',
                    help='path to latest checkpoint (default: none)')
parser.add_argument('--world-size', default=-1, type=int,
                    help='number of nodes for distributed training')
parser.add_argument('--rank', default=-1, type=int,
                    help='node rank for distributed training')
parser.add_argument('--dist-url', default='tcp://224.66.41.62:23456', type=str,
                    help='url used to set up distributed training')
parser.add_argument('--dist-backend', default='nccl', type=str,
                    help='distributed backend')
parser.add_argument('--seed', default=None, type=int,
                    help='seed for initializing training. ')
parser.add_argument('--gpu', default=None, type=int,
                    help='GPU id to use.')
parser.add_argument('--multiprocessing-distributed', action='store_true',
                    help='Use multi-processing distributed training to launch '
                         'N processes per node, which has N GPUs. This is the '
                         'fastest way to use PyTorch for either single node or '
                         'multi node data parallel training')

# moco specific configs:
parser.add_argument('--moco-dim', default=128, type=int,
                    help='feature dimension (default: 128)')
parser.add_argument('--moco-k', default=65536, type=int,
                    help='queue size; number of negative keys (default: 65536)')
parser.add_argument('--moco-m', default=0.999, type=float,
                    help='moco momentum of updating key encoder (default: 0.999)')
parser.add_argument('--moco-t', default=0.07, type=float,
                    help='softmax temperature (default: 0.07)')

# options for moco v2
parser.add_argument('--mlp', action='store_true',
                    help='use mlp head')
parser.add_argument('--aug-plus', action='store_true',
                    help='use moco v2 data augmentation')
parser.add_argument('--cos', action='store_true',
                    help='use cosine lr schedule')

def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.seed is not None:
        random.seed(args.seed)
        torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
        cudnn.deterministic = True
        warnings.warn('You have chosen to seed training. '
                      'This will turn on the CUDNN deterministic setting, '
                      'which can slow down your training considerably! '
                      'You may see unexpected behavior when restarting '
                      'from checkpoints.')

    if args.gpu is not None:
        warnings.warn('You have chosen a specific GPU. This will completely '
                      'disable data parallelism.')

    if args.dist_url == "env://" and args.world_size == -1:
        args.world_size = int(os.environ["WORLD_SIZE"])

    args.distributed = args.world_size > 1 or args.multiprocessing_distributed

    ngpus_per_node = torch.cuda.device_count()
    if args.multiprocessing_distributed:
        # Since we have ngpus_per_node processes per node, the total world_size
        # needs to be adjusted accordingly
        args.world_size = ngpus_per_node * args.world_size
        # Use torch.multiprocessing.spawn to launch distributed processes: the
        # main_worker process function
        mp.spawn(main_worker, nprocs=ngpus_per_node, args=(ngpus_per_node, args))
    else:
        # Simply call main_worker function
        main_worker(args.gpu, ngpus_per_node, args)


def main_worker(gpu, ngpus_per_node, args):
    args.gpu = gpu

    # suppress printing if not master
    if args.multiprocessing_distributed and args.gpu != 0:
        def print_pass(*args):
            pass
        builtins.print = print_pass

    if args.gpu is not None:
        print("Use GPU: {} for training".format(args.gpu))

    if args.distributed:
        if args.dist_url == "env://" and args.rank == -1:
            args.rank = int(os.environ["RANK"])
        if args.multiprocessing_distributed:
            # For multiprocessing distributed training, rank needs to be the
            # global rank among all the processes
            args.rank = args.rank * ngpus_per_node + gpu
        dist.init_process_group(backend=args.dist_backend, init_method=args.dist_url,
                                world_size=args.world_size, rank=args.rank)
    # create model
    print("=> creating model '{}'".format(args.arch))
    model = moco.builder.MoCo(
        models.__dict__[args.arch],
        args.moco_dim, args.moco_k, args.moco_m, args.moco_t, args.mlp)
    print(model)

    if args.distributed:
        # For multiprocessing distributed, DistributedDataParallel constructor
        # should always set the single device scope, otherwise,
        # DistributedDataParallel will use all available devices.
        if args.gpu is not None:
            torch.cuda.set_device(args.gpu)
            model.cuda(args.gpu)
            # When using a single GPU per process and per
            # DistributedDataParallel, we need to divide the batch size
            # ourselves based on the total number of GPUs we have
            args.batch_size = int(args.batch_size / ngpus_per_node)
            args.workers = int((args.workers + ngpus_per_node - 1) / ngpus_per_node)
            model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[args.gpu])
        else:
            model.cuda()
            # DistributedDataParallel will divide and allocate batch_size to all
            # available GPUs if device_ids are not set
            model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model)
    elif args.gpu is not None:
        torch.cuda.set_device(args.gpu)
        model = model.cuda(args.gpu)
        # comment out the following line for debugging
        raise NotImplementedError("Only DistributedDataParallel is supported.")
    else:
        # AllGather implementation (batch shuffle, queue update, etc.) in
        # this code only supports DistributedDataParallel.
        raise NotImplementedError("Only DistributedDataParallel is supported.")
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem ,Did you found the solution?